# How can I make jQuery wait for div display value to change to "block", then make ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

From what I've researched on setTimeout() and setInterval(), it seems this should work, but it breaks at the point it's time to stop waiting, and console outputs an error message.

I have a page set up to do a number of server-side and client-side performance tests, then do an ajax call to save the test results to the database. It was working great, but recently I added a browser test (based off of Google's Octane code). What I want to do is make jQuery wait until after Octane is done and has produced a final score and has populated a div with that score, then do the ajax call to save all of the test results. I've tried using setTimeout() in a recursive function to do that, but the code fails right before the saveData() ajax call is made. Octane will be running, the function will do as it should and keep calling itself every 5 seconds, then Octane completes and the function calls saveData(), and that's where it breaks.

This is the basic code structure:

```
 ...Octane code
    ...<div id="finalScore" style="display:none;">When Octane is done, it will change display of this div to block and populate it with test score</div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //set some vars
             var waitCounter = 0;


            var request = $.ajax({//this is a test of download time
                url: path to a text file
                type: "GET",
                success: function(result) {
                    //crunch some numbers

                    var requestUpload = $.ajax({//only want to do upload test if download was successful
                        url: //path to a file
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: formData,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data) {
                            //crunch some numbers

                            waitForClientScore();//new function, replaces saveData() below

                            //saveData(nDLSpeedMbps, nULSpeedMbps, nLoopSpeedMbps, nQuerySpeedMbps, nReadSpeedMbps, nWriteSpeedMbps, nAvgLoop, nAvgQuery, nAvgRead, nAvgWrite);
                        }
                    });

                    requestUpload.fail(function(xhr, status) {
                        //handle upload fail
                    });
                }
            });

            request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                //handle download fail
            });

            function clientScoreReady() {//is Octane done yet?
                var clientScoreDiv = document.getElementById('finalScore');
                var divDisplayValue = clientScoreDiv.style.display;
                return (divDisplayValue == "block");            
            }

            function waitForClientScore() {
                if (clientScoreReady()) {
                    clearTimeout(t);
                    saveData(nDLSpeedMbps, nULSpeedMbps, nLoopSpeedMbps, nQuerySpeedMbps, nReadSpeedMbps, nWriteSpeedMbps, nAvgLoop, nAvgQuery, nAvgRead, nAvgWrite);
                }
                else if (waitCounter >= 12) {//make 12 recursive calls max (60 sec)
                    clearTimeout(t);
                    console.log("timed out after 12 recursive calls");
                }
                else {//recursive function call
                    waitCounter = waitCounter + 1;
                    console.log(waitCounter);
                    t = setTimeout(waitForClientScore, 5000);
                }
            }

            function saveData(nDLSpeedMbps, nULSpeedMbps, nLoopSpeedMbps, nQuerySpeedMbps, nReadSpeedMbps, nWriteSpeedMbps, nAvgLoop, nAvgQuery, nAvgRead, nAvgWrite){

                //put all argument values into userdata struct

                $.ajax({
                    url : path to page that saves userdata to DB
                    type: "POST",
                    data : userdata,
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        //handle success
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        //handle fail
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
```

This is what happens when I execute the page and watch the console:  Octane is running, and the waitForClientScore() function sees that Octane isn't done, so it successfully increments waitCounter and calls itself in 5 seconds. Then when Octane is done, Octane populates the div and changes its display from none to block. WaitForClientScore() sees that display is block, and calls saveData(). Then the ajax call inside of saveData() fails -- console outputs a message saying "$ is not defined".

saveData() (commented out) was working fine before it was moved to inside of waitForClientScore().

I tried putting waitForClientScore() inside the upload success function, but the same thing happened with a different error message from console. waitForClientScore() keeps calling itself until Octane is done, but then console outputs a message saying that waitForClientScore() is not a function.

Comment: Can you paste in the error messages? Also in chrome go to Inspect element->Network Tab then search for that last ajax request. Click on it and then view the response tab and request tab to see if there is any errors coming back that might help you.

Comment: Its also possible you have a MySql error that wouldn't be showing up in your client side JavaScript console.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
It's referencing the $ in saveData()'s "$.ajax" line

Comment: Did you try jQuery.ajax instead? Also can you try to console.log(jQuery(body)); It might be because jQuery is not available in your current scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try jQuery.ajax instead? Also can you try to console.log(jQuery(body)); It might be because jQuery is not available in your current scope. –  battletoilet

Comment: Ah, that did it. Strange, since it uses "$" right up to that point, and "$" works without the recursion. I think you're right about the scope inside the recursive function changing such that "$" is no longer available.